# XSLT transformation of multiple "flat" XML files into tree-like XML

Tags: xml, xslt, saxon

I use saxon 11he

file 1.xml describes all objects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ADDRESSOBJECTS>
  <OBJECT OBJECTID="105037985" NAME="OTHER PARENT" LEVEL="2" STARTDATE="2022-07-20" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT OBJECTID="1171388" NAME="PARENT" LEVEL="2" STARTDATE="1900-01-01" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT OBJECTID="1171421" NAME="CHILD 1" LEVEL="6" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT OBJECTID="1171502" NAME="CHILD 2" LEVEL="6" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT OBJECTID="1171612" NAME="CHILD 3" LEVEL="4" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT OBJECTID="1171731" NAME="CHILD 4" LEVEL="4" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <OBJECT OBJECTID="1171761" NAME="CHILD 5" LEVEL="6" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
</ADDRESSOBJECTS>
```

file 2.xml describes the hierarchical dependency:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ITEMS>
  <ITEM OBJECTID="1170420" PARENTOBJID="1171380" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <ITEM OBJECTID="1170423" PARENTOBJID="1171380" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <ITEM OBJECTID="1171421" PARENTOBJID="1171388" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <ITEM OBJECTID="1171421" PARENTOBJID="1171388" STARTDATE="2001-01-01" ENDDATE="2004-12-26" ISACTIVE="0" />
  <ITEM OBJECTID="1171502" PARENTOBJID="1171388" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <ITEM OBJECTID="1171612" PARENTOBJID="1171388" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <ITEM OBJECTID="1171731" PARENTOBJID="1171388" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
  <ITEM OBJECTID="1171761" PARENTOBJID="1171388" STARTDATE="2004-12-27" ENDDATE="2079-06-06" ISACTIVE="1" />
</ITEMS>
```

I need to build a tree from file 1 objects by hierarchy from file 2

I'm stuck even at the first level, there are 4-5 levels in total, and there are two hierarchy files, there is another independent hierarchy (but it doesn't matter)
First, how to return to the context of file 1 in for-each? (see below xsl file)
Secondly, how to select a node in for-each by the 2nd file from the 1st file and work with its attributes? Because, I need to copy a lot more attributes and pull them in the way that I have, this is every new search and, accordingly, an increase execution time.
Thirdly, it is necessary to sort by @NAME (from the 1st file), although it is not necessary, but interesting.

I made some crutches, I assume that everything is done differently:

```
<xsl:transform
 xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
 version="2.0"
>
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes" encoding="UTF-8"/>


<xsl:variable name="objectid">
  <xsl:value-of
          select="//OBJECT[@LEVEL='2' and @ISACTIVE='1' and starts-with(@NAME, 'PARENT')]/@OBJECTID"/>
</xsl:variable>

<xsl:template match="/">
<ROOT OBJECTID="{$objectid}">
  <xsl:for-each select="document('2.xml')//ITEM[@PARENTOBJID=$objectid and @ISACTIVE='1']">
    <xsl:variable name="childid">
      <xsl:value-of select="@OBJECTID"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="childname">
      <xsl:value-of
              select="document('1.xml')//OBJECT[@OBJECTID=$childid and @ISACTIVE='1']/@NAME"/>
    </xsl:variable>
    <xsl:variable name="childlevel">
      <xsl:value-of
              select="document('1.xml')//OBJECT[@OBJECTID=$childid and @ISACTIVE='1']/@LEVEL"/>
    </xsl:variable>
     <ELEMENT OBJECTID="{$childid}" NAME="{$childname}" LEVEL="{$childlevel}" />
  </xsl:for-each>
</ROOT>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:transform>
```

output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT OBJECTID="1171388">
   <ELEMENT OBJECTID="1171421" NAME="CHILD 1" LEVEL="6"/>
   <ELEMENT OBJECTID="1171502" NAME="CHILD 2" LEVEL="6"/>
   <ELEMENT OBJECTID="1171612" NAME="CHILD 3" LEVEL="4"/>
   <ELEMENT OBJECTID="1171731" NAME="CHILD 4" LEVEL="4"/>
   <ELEMENT OBJECTID="1171761" NAME="CHILD 5" LEVEL="6"/>
</ROOT>
```

PS: In general, i need to get something like this structure.

```
<REGION>
   <DISTRICT>
     <MUNICIPALDISTRICT>
       <LOCALITY>
         <DRIVEWAY>
           <HOUSE>
           </HOUSE>
         </DRIVEWAY>
       </LOCALITY>
     </MUNICIPALDISTRICT>
   </DISTRICT>
</REGION>
```

the element of each nested level is called by its own name

PPS: I hope I've made my confused thoughts clear.

Comment: 1. Please post the **exact** result you expect to get. There is no REGION anywhere in the input. 2. There are duplicate ITEMs in file 2.xml; apparently an object can have  different parents at different times. It's not clear how you want to handle such situation.

Comment: @michael-hor257k , 1. tags like REGION, etc., are applied depending on the LEVEL value / 2.  attribute ISACTIVE="1". Basically, Martin Honnen answered, it works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a key e.g. `<xsl:key name="child" match="ITEM" use="@PARENTOBJID"/>` and then you can follow  e.g. `key('child', @OBJECTID, doc('2.xml'))` to find element children of the currently processed `ITEM`.

Trying to use that it seems you need a second key to look back in the main document:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="3.0"
  xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
  exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
  expand-text="yes">
  
  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>
  
  <xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="child" match="ITEM" use="@PARENTOBJID"/>
  
  <xsl:key name="object" match="OBJECT" use="@OBJECTID"/>
  
  <xsl:variable name="doc1" select="/"/>
  
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="ADDRESSOBJECTS/OBJECT[@LEVEL = 2]"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="OBJECT[@LEVEL = 2]">
    <ROOT>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, key('child', @OBJECTID, $doc2)/key('object', @OBJECTID, $doc1)"/>
    </ROOT>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match="OBJECT">
    <ELEMENT>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, key('child', @OBJECTID, $doc2)/key('object', @OBJECTID, $doc1)"/>
    </ELEMENT>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:param name="doc2" select="doc('2.xml')"/>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

[Online sample](https://martin-honnen.github.io/xslt3fiddle/?xslt=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3Cxsl%3Astylesheet%20xmlns%3Axsl%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F1999%2FXSL%2FTransform%22%0D%0A%20%20version%3D%223.0%22%0D%0A%20%20xmlns%3Axs%3D%22http%3A%2F%2Fwww.w3.org%2F2001%2FXMLSchema%22%0D%0A%20%20exclude-result-prefixes%3D%22%23all%22%0D%0A%20%20expand-text%3D%22yes%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aoutput%20indent%3D%22yes%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Amode%20on-no-match%3D%22shallow-copy%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Akey%20name%3D%22child%22%20match%3D%22ITEM%22%20use%3D%22%40PARENTOBJID%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Akey%20name%3D%22object%22%20match%3D%22OBJECT%22%20use%3D%22%40OBJECTID%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Avariable%20name%3D%22doc1%22%20select%3D%22%2F%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22ADDRESSOBJECTS%2FOBJECT%5B%40LEVEL%20%3D%202%5D%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22OBJECT%5B%40LEVEL%20%3D%202%5D%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CROOT%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%2C%20key%28%27child%27%2C%20%40OBJECTID%2C%20%24doc2%29%2Fkey%28%27object%27%2C%20%40OBJECTID%2C%20%24doc1%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FROOT%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22OBJECT%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3CELEMENT%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aapply-templates%20select%3D%22%40*%2C%20key%28%27child%27%2C%20%40OBJECTID%2C%20%24doc2%29%2Fkey%28%27object%27%2C%20%40OBJECTID%2C%20%24doc1%29%22%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3C%2FELEMENT%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Atemplate%20match%3D%22%2F%22%20name%3D%22xsl%3Ainitial-template%22%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Anext-match%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cxsl%3Acomment%3ERun%20with%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-name%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27xsl%3Aproduct-version%27%29%7D%20%7Bsystem-property%28%27Q%7Bhttp%3A%2F%2Fsaxon.sf.net%2F%7Dplatform%27%29%7D%3C%2Fxsl%3Acomment%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Atemplate%3E%0D%0A%20%20%0D%0A%20%20%3Cxsl%3Aparam%20name%3D%22doc2%22%3E%0D%0A%3CITEMS%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CITEM%20OBJECTID%3D%221170420%22%20PARENTOBJID%3D%221171380%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CITEM%20OBJECTID%3D%221170423%22%20PARENTOBJID%3D%221171380%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CITEM%20OBJECTID%3D%221171421%22%20PARENTOBJID%3D%221171388%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CITEM%20OBJECTID%3D%221171421%22%20PARENTOBJID%3D%221171388%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222001-01-01%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222004-12-26%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%220%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CITEM%20OBJECTID%3D%221171502%22%20PARENTOBJID%3D%221171388%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CITEM%20OBJECTID%3D%221171612%22%20PARENTOBJID%3D%221171388%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CITEM%20OBJECTID%3D%221171731%22%20PARENTOBJID%3D%221171388%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3CITEM%20OBJECTID%3D%221171761%22%20PARENTOBJID%3D%221171388%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FITEMS%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3C%2Fxsl%3Aparam%3E%0D%0A%3C%2Fxsl%3Astylesheet%3E%0D%0A&input=%3C%3Fxml%20version%3D%221.0%22%20encoding%3D%22utf-8%22%3F%3E%0D%0A%3CADDRESSOBJECTS%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COBJECT%20OBJECTID%3D%22105037985%22%20NAME%3D%22OTHER%20PARENT%22%20LEVEL%3D%222%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222022-07-20%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COBJECT%20OBJECTID%3D%221171388%22%20NAME%3D%22PARENT%22%20LEVEL%3D%222%22%20STARTDATE%3D%221900-01-01%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COBJECT%20OBJECTID%3D%221171421%22%20NAME%3D%22CHILD%201%22%20LEVEL%3D%226%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COBJECT%20OBJECTID%3D%221171502%22%20NAME%3D%22CHILD%202%22%20LEVEL%3D%226%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COBJECT%20OBJECTID%3D%221171612%22%20NAME%3D%22CHILD%203%22%20LEVEL%3D%224%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COBJECT%20OBJECTID%3D%221171731%22%20NAME%3D%22CHILD%204%22%20LEVEL%3D%224%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%20%20%3COBJECT%20OBJECTID%3D%221171761%22%20NAME%3D%22CHILD%205%22%20LEVEL%3D%226%22%20STARTDATE%3D%222004-12-27%22%20ENDDATE%3D%222079-06-06%22%20ISACTIVE%3D%221%22%20%2F%3E%0D%0A%3C%2FADDRESSOBJECTS%3E%0D%0A&input-type=XML).

I guess you want to filter out some attributes with an empty template.

Comment: can you give a little more detail?

Comment: It's cool,simple and complex.But I can't understand how it is possible to bind the dependency of records from the 3rd file to objects with LEVEL>=6 from the 1st file?In the 3rd file,there are entries with the conditional tag SUBOBJ and the connection with the 1st file through the 2nd,also through PARENTOBJID and OBJECTID Only crutches come to mind,either somehow through for-each as before,or using sed to comb the 3rd file to look like the 1st and add it to the 1st.I don’t understand how to bind this SUBOBJ to OBJECT.I understand that you have already answered the question,but can you tell me

Comment: @SergeyZakharov, I think you should ask a new question where you show the necessary details of the third file, its relations to the other files, the output you want.

Comment: I wrote a new question, it seems to work, but one moment is not clear, please look - [Continuation - 2 xml files of objects and 1 with hierarchy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73339466/xslt-transformation-of-multiple-flat-xml-files-into-tree-like-xml-continuatio)